# Next protocol in MPLS header

Tags: mpls

How come MPLS header has no next protocol ID field?
How can a parser tell for sure which protocol is next?

BOS field only indicates that the next header is not MPLS, which is not enough to distinguish between IPv4 and Ethernet for example.

Parsing the next protocol header itself for protocol ID is also prone to errors. (Might easily confuse IP header with Ethernet header - since Destination MAC addresses are quite random).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next header after MPLS BOS can be determined without the "next protocol" field since the router that originated this label knows to which service it belongs.

L2VPN(VPLS, VPWS): next header is ETH.
L3VPNv4: next header is IPv4.
6PE, 6VPE: next header is IPv6.

So after terminating the service label (VPN label) it knows what header to expect next.

Answer (score 4):

The next protocol ID is used by hosts when processing a datagram so they know which process to hand the datagram to.  But hosts never process MPLS datagrams.  The MPLS header is stripped off before it reaches them.

LSR routers do not process datagrams beyond the MPLS header, so there is no need for a next protocol ID.

Comment: I have a concrete example of a case where an LSR should know the next protocol ID of MPLS. Suppose I want to load balance L3VPN (or VPLS) traffic within an MPLS core. How will the LSR calculate the hash value for the loadbalancing function if it doesn't know the exact header structure? In case it will take into account only label information all traffic will flow out the same interface, wouldn't it?

Comment: You can't load balance that way.  You would have to create two TE tunnels (two LSPs) in order to load balance.  In that case the ingress router does the hashing.

Comment: Cool thanks. So as of today, load balancing for all VPN traffic can be acomplished only by using TE tunnels?

Comment: Today and the foreseeable future.

Comment: Mmm ok. How about load balancing over LAG??

Comment: @sergeyrar, that depends on what you mean by "load balancing." Round-robin, per-packet load balancing is not a good thing for LAG. What you want is to balance by flow. Whenever you load balance by frame/packet you increase the problems with out-of-order packet delivery that can actually slow connection-oriented protocols like TCP, and completely kill real-time protocols like VoIP and video.

Comment: @Ron Maupin: Yes I mean per flow. How can a parser identify which protocol is encapsulated within MPLS to implement a flow based load balancing?

Comment: @sergeyrar, ECMP is based on a routing protocol with layer-3 packets, but MPLS is label-switched, not based on routed packets. You seem to be confusing multiple things.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, I fixed it - I meant load balancing.

Comment: @sergeyrar, parsers do not need to identify what is in an MPLS frame. MPLS is switched only on the labels of the frame. It is label-switched until the last label is popped and the packet is exposed. You determine which direction to send the packet before it is labeled, then MPLS takes over to switch the frame by pushing and popping labels.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90476/discussion-between-sergeyrar-and-ron-maupin).